# Linux file creation size

Tags: c, linux, file, ubuntu

If I create a file in ubuntu like this: "echo "asd" > file.txt" and I do a ls -l file.txt it says that it's size is 4 bytes, but I only wrote 3 (asd). If I do "cat file.txt" it shows the 3 chars that I have added. Why is the file 4 bytes large?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`asd` + new line character = 4 bytes

```
$ echo asd | wc -c
4
$ echo -n asd | wc -c
3
$ echo asd | hd
00000000  61 73 64 0a                                       |asd.|
00000004
```

-n in echo switches newline off

`hd` shows you a hexdump of the stream. You see the `0a` character at the end. That is the fourth character, newline.